# How to update OpenStruct value with condition

Tags: ruby, openstruct

How can I update values of `OpenStruct` when a conditions is met?
I thought like this:

```
o = OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2)
o.each_pair{|k,v| v = 3 if v.even?  }
```

But this code doesn't work.

I could update by this code, but it's quite hard to read.

```
OpenStruct.new(o.each_pair.map{|k,v| [k, v.even? ? 3 : v]  }.to_h)
```

Is there better way to update `OpenStruct` values by a condition?

Comment: `o.b = 3 if o.b.even? #=> 3; o #=> #<OpenStruct a=1, b=3>; o.to_h #=> {:a=>1, :b=>3}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better but still not super clear:

```
o.to_h.each { |k, v| o[k] = 3 if v.even? }
```

EDIT - Better yet:

```
o.each_pair { |k, v| o[k] = 3 if v.even? }
```

This looks pretty good to me. You just can't mutate directly via the iterator.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear what I want to do. I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no easy method to update values in `OpenStruct` class?